# Does increasing the middle class result in lower birth rates?

Tags: economics, population, birth

I saw an article or two about the phenomenon of well off upper class families having large families. It claimed that his broke the trend of increased economic status resulting in smaller families that has been occurring in developed and developing countries for the last 400 years or so. Is this trend actually documented? How strong is the correlation?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to some of those articles where this claim is being made.

Comment: Please reference the article (with a hyperlink, and/or the title and the name of the publication), and if possible quote the sentence or two from it which you are questioning.

Comment: I couldn't find the article about well educated upper middle class women breaking the trend, but I found plenty of support for the correlation. So, I guess this is already considered established, not something to be skeptical of.